# how to fill inside a region of an image in opencv python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have found the boundaries of an image like this:

[image]

Now I need to fill inside of the region (it is a breast tissue). Is there any functions in opencv or other modules in python like skimage through which I can do that?? something like maybe `imfill` in MATLAB.

Comment: [floodFill](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#floodfill)?

Answer (score 0):

A simple floodfill will not work in this case. The image you have provided looks like one single contour but it has multiple holes in it. Before you can apply flood fill, I suggest you fill the holes in the line using spline curves. Once done you can apply [floodfill](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#floodfill).

[image: The broken line]

Comment: To fill the holes you can simply do a [morphological closing](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html#closing) `closing = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)`.